# Can't access Ubuntu Server with SSH after doing something with iptables

Tags: networking, server, ssh, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to run a MC-Server on an Ubuntu Sever (Oracle Cloud). I already port forwarded 25565 and 22 but still couldn't access the server. I found these commands on another tutorial, but when I executed them my SSH connection stopped, and now it just says "Network Error: Connection timed out!"

```sh
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload
sudo iptables -F
```

I don't understand much about this topic, so please keep your answer simple.

Comment: `sudo iptables -F` erased all your prior work. So now you have no rules at all.

Comment: You will have to show us your overall context, `sudo iptables -xvnL`. Have you set default policies to DROP?